# RSpec magic for testing an array's none? method?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec2

I have an `Array`/`Enumerable` where each entity is a `Hash`. Using RSpec what is the most idiomatic way to test for "none of the entries in the enumerable should have a key called `'body'`"?

I can do something like:

```
array.none? {|thing| thing.key? 'body'}.should be_true
```

or

```
array.should be_none {|thing| thing.key? 'body'}
```

...but there must be a more RSpec-way of doing this, correct?

I can't seem to find an appropriate [built-in matcher](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-11/docs/built-in-matchers). Is the answer a custom matcher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use
`responses.should be_none { |response| response.key? 'body' }`

Between the two you gave. This would be slightly more helpful with an error like

"Expected none? to return true"

where as your first example would say something like

"expected False:false class to be true"

The third option I can see would be something like

```
 keys = responses.map { |response| response.keys }.flatten.uniq
 keys.should_not include "body"
```

This would give an error like

expected ["foo", "bar", "body"] not to include "body"

Other than that, looking at https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-11/docs/built-in-matchers/satisfy-matcher

you could try

`responses.should satisfy { |response| not response.keys.include? "body" }`

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be turning the `be_none` statement around with `be_any`:

```
responses.should_not be_any { |response| response.key? 'body' }
```

I would assume that the result is equivalent as `any?` is the negation of `none?`.

It's mostly a question of which option you feel is the most intuitive to read and, as EnabrenTane mentions, if you think the error messages are helpful enough.